# Transfer amount from a user account to another user account

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a database that contains users data like `useraccountid`, `userid`, `balance`,   `totalwithdrawal`,  `creationdate`. I have finished with the structure and the code but keep giving me no response and the fund on the sender account doesn't change.

**below is the HTML form that handles the transaction**

```
<div id="make-trans" class="col-xs-12">
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS-->                     
    <div id="w2w" class="container jumbotron">
        <h3 class="card-title center jumbotron1" style="background-color: #f88f20; color: #fff;"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-credit-card"></i> Wallet To Wallet</h3>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" role="form" novalidate>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Agent Account ID">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">                                  
                    <input type='number' name='balance' class="form-control" id="sname" placeholder="Amount">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9 center">
                    <a href="wallet-to-wallet.php" type="submit" name="submit" class="outline-btn info">Transfer</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>              
    </div>
</div>
```

**below is the php code that handle the transaction**

```
class TransactionDemo {

    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_NAME = 'trans';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = '';


    public function transfer($from, $to, $amount) {

        try {
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

            // get available amount of the transferer account
            $sql = 'SELECT balance FROM useraccount WHERE userid=:from';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(":from" => $from));
            $availableAmount = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            if ($availableAmount < $amount) {
                echo 'No money in your account';
                return false;
            }
            // deduct from the transferred account
            $sql_update_from = 'UPDATE useraccount
                SET balance = balance - :balance
                WHERE userid = :from';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql_update_from);
            $stmt->execute(array(":from" => $from, ":balance" => $amount));
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            // add to the receiving account
            $sql_update_to = 'UPDATE useraccount
                                SET balance = balance + :balance
                                WHERE userid = :to';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql_update_to);
            $stmt->execute(array(":to" => $to, ":balance" => $balance));

            // commit the transaction
            $this->pdo->commit();

            echo 'The amount has been transferred successfully';

            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the database connection
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // open database connection
        $conStr = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", self::DB_HOST, self::DB_NAME);
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($conStr, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * close the database connection
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        // close the database connection
        $this->pdo = null;
    }

}

?>
```

now I created a `transaction.php` and like it on the form action="" but I am not getting any error and the fund does not move.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$stmt->closeCursor()`?

Comment: .. besides that first query could be more like `UPDATE useraccount
                SET balance = balance - :balance
                WHERE userid = :from' AND balance >= :balance`    then that `SELECT` can also be skipped..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i was able to remove the SELECT still the issue, the page will reload but nothing happen

Comment: i never said it would fix it consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DTSHVrxFGR6sikJF7Np5L/7) to possibly handle it complety in a transaction.. Toy around a bit with the balances for `userid = 1`  And research the manual how or why it works..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i was able to insert the code but giving me an error....... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\dashboard\ajax\makeTransaction.php on line 5..  where am i suppose to insert the code.  the code structure seems incorrect

Comment: @RaymondNijland you can update it on the link u pasted earlier https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DTSHVrxFGR6sikJF7Np5L/2

Comment: Not sure you never let read me the code or which error you got after trying mine example suggestion for that matter the problem could be anything..  But most likely mine [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DTSHVrxFGR6sikJF7Np5L/7) is more suitable to be handled with a MySQL [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) instead..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thetable u create has on id=1 and 2............... and the code will be between the two id. but in a situation whereby you are dealing with many users with different id and they are to send fund to each other.

Comment: yes i have that example like that with a reason, handling it as one transaction between two users... if you need to deal more transactions from one user to multiple users use a loop per money transaction.. trust me on this that this is the most easy and most save approach to implement in this case..

Comment: @RaymondNijland can u update the link with that so has to see how u structure it........... this is an opportunity for me to learn. Please

Comment: @RaymondNijland check my new answer below and also the new issue am facing

Answer (score 0):

you added **wallet-to-wallet.php** in this href.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9 center">
                <a href="wallet-to-wallet.php" type="submit" name="submit" class="outline-btn info">Transfer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Remove this or move the code from **transaction.php** and paste in  **wallet-to-wallet.php**  page.

Comment: check my new answer and the new found problem

Comment: i need more answer

Answer (score -1):

```
 * PHP MySQL Transaction Demo
 */
class TransactionDemo {

    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_NAME = 'transferfund';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = '';

    /**
     * Open the database connection
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // open database connection
        $conStr = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", self::DB_HOST, self::DB_NAME);
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($conStr, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * PDO instance
     * @var PDO 
     */
    private $pdo = null;

    /**
     * Transfer money between two accounts
     * @param int $from
     * @param int $to
     * @param float $amount
     * @return true on success or false on failure.
     */
    public function transfer($from, $to, $balance) {

        try {
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

            // get available amount of the transferer account
            $sql = 'SELECT balance FROM useraccount WHERE userid=:from';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(":from" => $from));
            $availableAmount = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            if ($availableAmount < $balance) {
                echo 'Insufficient amount to transfer';
                return false;
            }
            // deduct from the transferred account
            $sql_update_from = 'UPDATE useraccount
                SET balance = balance - :balance
                WHERE userid = :from';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql_update_from);
            $stmt->execute(array(":from" => $from, ":balance" => $balance));
            $stmt->closeCursor();


            // add to the receiving account
            $sql_update_to = 'UPDATE useraccount
                                SET balance = balance + :balance
                                WHERE userid = :to';
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql_update_to);
            $stmt->execute(array(":to" => $to, ":balance" => $balance));

            // commit the transaction


                if ($this->pdo->commit()) {

                    header("Location: ../wallet2wallet_success.php");


                }else{

                    header("Location: ../wallet2wallet_error.php");

                } 
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * close the database connection
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        // close the database connection
        $this->pdo = null;
    }

}



 // test the transfer method
$obj = new TransactionDemo();


// transfer from account 1 to 2
$from = isset($_POST["from"]);
$to = isset($_POST["to"]);
$balance = isset($_POST["balance"]);

$obj->transfer ($_POST["from"], $_POST["to"], $_POST["balance"]);
```

i was able to solve the problem with this codes above,Thanks for your contribution

```
<div id="w2w" class="container jumbotron">
 <h3 class="card-title center jumbotron1" style="background-color: #f88f20; color: #fff; margin-top: -15px;"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-credit-card"></i> Wallet To Wallet</h3>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="ajax/makeTransaction.php" role="form" method = "POST">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
<select id="inputState" type="number"  class="form-control" name="from" class="form-control">
<option selected><?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?></option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
<input type="number"  class="form-control" name="to" placeholder="Receiver Agent Account ID" value="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">                                          
<input type='number'  class="form-control" name="balance" placeholder="Amount" value="">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9 center">
<button type="submit" name="transfer" class="outline-btn info">Transfer</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>              
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a complete solution so why did you add it to the answers area?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner   its complete but i have a new problem in it

Comment: That should have been a new question. Instead, you added to it, that isn't how things are done on Stack.